# Inconsistent number of badges

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

The number of badges doesn't seem to be consistent between the profile of (a now deleted spam) user.

Does this user have 1 badge, or none?

[image]

The activity tab shows:

[image]

So it seems the user has one badge. Why is it shown in the activity tab, but not on the profile (while the number is accurate)?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to said user?

Comment: As stated it is now deleted, so no... Hopefully the screenshots will do.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought we could view deleted users. Never mind! The link may still be useful to SE employees if you want a retrospective answer to what happened. I'm assuming they can see [*everything...*](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/de/2c/86/de2c866545ec46df289b2f4957d1dcf9.jpg)

Comment: @Duncan: No, we can't.

Answer (score -1):

"This user has not earned any badges" section is just cached, while the header of this section is not, which makes it look like a bug. I just checked it.

Comment: How do you know that is cached and the other is not? Why isn't the number cached then? And then the profile page?

Comment: @Pat I tested it on one user. Why should I post the  link to his account?

Comment: I didn't ask you to post his account. I seems your post is a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Pat OK. 29 mins ago I upvoted an answer of new user. In 5 mins he got the badge. It displayed: "Badges(1)" and then "This user has not earned any badges" . Now instead of "This user has not earned any badges" I can see the badge (appeared just now).

Comment: Okay. I understand, but why the one list is cached and the other not, and why is the number not cached?

Comment: @Pat Ask devs. I dunno :) That's their decision.

Comment: Well, that is my actual question...

Comment: @Pat I think because the second section spends some time to calculate rareness of badge (some script runs).